# What is the purpose of the .validate line in this Firebase Realtime Database security rule?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In this example rule for the members node, this node is going to be filled with `UID`s. So why would the incoming data have children `username` and `email` that this rule is checking? Does this rule ensure that `UID`, `username`, and `email` are all written into the node?

```json
"rules": {
  ///...
  "members": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "root.child('groups/groupID/admin').val() === auth.uid",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['username', 'email'])", /// ???
        "$other": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $uid && auth.uid === $other",
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **key** if those node is `$uid`, but it has to have `username` and `email` child nodes. This is a common way to ensure that the node will always have at least those properties.